# PHP project migration from windows to linux (Code not working)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm migrating my full php project from windows to ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. I'm using xampp for apache7 and mysql v.14 services in windows and Im running apache and mysql standalone services in ubuntu. The project reads and writes data perfectly on the windows platform but not on the ubuntu platform. I didn't alter any codes except the path of the directories. The project can read the data on the ubuntu database but cannot write data to it.

I've been trying to see the errors on mysql logs but can't find any possible causes.

In ubuntu

Permissions to the sql user "root" has been granted (full grant). Query to the database is fine but cannot insert data to the database. PHP7 and SQL in the ubuntu systems is working fine.

Code below runs perfectly in the windows system but not in ubuntu.

```
function insertion($sqlStatement,$employee_number,$lname, $fname, $mname, $birthdate, $gender, $region, $province, $municipality, $position, $designation, $cellphone, $email, $alter_email, $employeee_number, $code, $username, $password, $date_created, $cluster, $contact, $office, $division, $access,$user){

if(
    $sqlStatement &&
    $sqlStatement -> bind_param("ssssssdddddssssssssssssss",  $employee_number,$lname, $fname, $mname, $birthdate, $gender, $region, $province, $municipality, $position, $designation, $cellphone, $email, $alter_email, $employeee_number, $code, $username, $password, $date_created, $cluster, $contact, $office, $division,$access,$user) &&
    $sqlStatement->execute()

)   {

}

}

// SQL Statement

$sql_insert_query= "INSERT INTO tblemployee(EMP_NUMBER,LAST_M, FIRST_M, MIDDLE_M, BIRTH_D, SEX_C,REGION_C, PROVINCE_C, CITYMUN_C,POSITION_C, DESIGNATION,MOBILEPHONE, EMAIL, ALTER_EMAIL, AGENCY_EMP_NO, CODE, UNAME, PSWORD, DATE_CREATED,CLUSTER, LANDPHONE, OFFICE_STATION, DIVISION_C, ACCESSLIST, ACCESSTYPE)VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?,?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

This statement is actually working including the whole process up to the .execute() part in the windows system. I tried predefining the data  to be inserted `(i.e INSERT INTO tblemployee (DIVISION_C) VALUES ('INFO');)` at the sql statement in the ubuntu and it works but not on this question marks.

Comment: Maybe your table structures are a bit different. You need to get some error message to know

Comment: Like the number of actual columns? There are no errors at all even at the logs.

Comment: Yes. Double check anything which you take for granted.

Comment: Is there any code difference between the two platform? (ubuntu vs. windows)

Comment: How do you check for MySQLi errors? Have you got exception mode switched on?

Comment: On my previous code, I just use the "or die(mysqli_error)" sort of thing after the execute. Please teach me how to switch on the exception mode.